# Matlab `outerjoin`: How to specify `RowNames` for `Keys`

Tags: matlab, outer-join

Matlab's documentation for `outerjoin` says that the "row labels" can be used for the `Keys`.  It doesn't provide the synatx for doing so.  My attempts have not met with success:

```
>> A=table([1;2],'VariableNames',{'Av1'},'RowNames',{'hot','dog'})
A = 
           Av1
           ___
    hot    1  
    dog    2  

>> B=table([3;4],'VariableNames',{'Bv1'},'RowNames',{'hot','dog'})
B = 
           Bv1
           ___
    hot    3  
    dog    4  

>> outerjoin(A,B)
Error using table/outerjoin (line 114)
Cannot find a common table variable to use as a key variable. 

>> outerjoin(A,B,'Keys','RowNames')
Error using table/outerjoin (line 114)
Unrecognized variable name 'RowNames'.
```

I'm wondering how to interpret the documentation.  Any help would be appreciated.

**AFTERNOTE**

It seems that the documentation is missing more than just how to
specify `RowNames` for `Keys`.  It also doesn't describe the default
keys.  From tests, its seems the default keys are columns wih matching
names:

```
A=array2table( [ 1 1 10; 1 2 20; 2 1 1; 2 2 20],...
   'VariableNames',{'k1','k2','d'} )
B=array2table( [ 1 1 100; 1 2 200; 2 1 1; 2 2 200],...
   'VariableNames',{'k1','k2','d'} )
outerjoin(A,B,'MergeKeys',true)

A = 
    k1    k2    d 
    __    __    __
    1     1     10
    1     2     20
    2     1      1
    2     2     20
B = 
    k1    k2     d 
    __    __    ___
    1     1     100
    1     2     200
    2     1       1
    2     2     200
ans = 
    k1    k2     d 
    __    __    ___
    1     1      10
    1     1     100
    1     2      20
    1     2     200
    2     1       1
    2     2      20
    2     2     200

A=array2table( [ 1 1 10; 1 2 20; 2 1 1; 2 2 20],...
   'VariableNames',{'k1','k2','d'} )
B=array2table( [ 1 1 100; 1 2 200; 2 1 1; 2 2 200],...
   'VariableNames',{'k1','k2','e'} )
outerjoin(A,B,'MergeKeys',true)

A = 
    k1    k2    d 
    __    __    __
    1     1     10
    1     2     20
    2     1      1
    2     2     20
B = 
    k1    k2     e 
    __    __    ___
    1     1     100
    1     2     200
    2     1       1
    2     2     200
ans = 
    k1    k2    d      e 
    __    __    __    ___
    1     1     10    100
    1     2     20    200
    2     1      1      1
    2     2     20    200
```

Comment: That documentation page is not at all clear on this, you are right. At the bottom of the page (at least in the [online version of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html#btx2ndz-1_seealso)) there is a question "Was this topic helpful?". Click "No", and describe your question there. You're likely to get clarification within a day or two, and they'll also fix the documentation.

Comment: Read what one of the Mathworks staff says on this here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/262818

Comment: @Cris Luengo: I did indeed submit feedback. Thanks. If they respond, I will emphasize that it would be advantageous for Matlab to make the argument/functionality protocol as consistent as possible across the various `join`s.  They are competing with SQL, which doesn't have all these inconsistencies.

Comment: @Sardar Usama: Thanks for the link to the thread. I have  to admit that I don't agree with the answer, which says something about many-to-many matches. I don't see that in the OP's description of the problem. Outer joining is also a well established concept in the SQL world, and it doesn't imply many-to-many matches. Mention is made of `setdiff`, and I'm sure it can be combined with other joins as a work-around.

Comment: It seems conceptually simpler, however, to copy `RowNames` into its own field (which I've yet to try). I was hoping to avoid cluttering up my code.  The more I do that, the more it strays from the alternative of lean SQL. At some point, it simply isn't worth it to use the Matlab code patterns, despite the code overhead of linking to Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMW provided the answer by citing the online documentation "[Use Row Labels as Grouping or Key Variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/limitations-of-tables-and-timetables.html#d119e31431)".  A table's `RowNames` will be used as the `Keys` argument if the keyword `Row` is specified.  `Row` refers to the name of the 1st dimension rather than to an actual field.

The above solution is only for R2016b onward.  The solution for earlier releases is to copy `RowNames` to an actual field, then use the field for the `Keys` argument.